# How to get a response from a script back to Hudson and to fail/success emails?

Tags: hudson

I'm starting a Python script from a Hudson job. The script is started though 'Execute Windows batch command' in build section as 'python my_script.py'

Now I'd need to get some data created by the script back to Hudson and add it to the fail/success emails. My current approach is that the Python script writes data to stderr which is read to a temp file by the batch and then taken into an environment variable. I can see the environment variable correctly right after the script execution (using set command), but in the post-build actions it's not visible any more. The email sending is probably done in different process, so the variables are not visible anymore. I'm accessing the env vars in the email as ${ENV, varname} (or actually in debug mode as $ENV to print them all)

Is there a way to make the environment variable global inside Hudson?

Or can someone provide a better solution for getting data back from Python script to Hudson.

All the related parts (Hudson, batch and Python script) are under my control and can be modified as needed.

Thanks.

Comment: Didn't find any direct solution to this. At the moment getting the build log (script output) as part of the emails, but still cannot get only selected/wanted lines and not as part of the email subject field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every build step get's is own shell. This implies, that your environment variables are only valid within the build step.

You can just write the data in a nice format to the std output (use a header that is easy to identify) and if the job fails, the data output gets attached in the email.

If you insist on only putting in the data, you can use the following token for the *Editable Email Notification* post build action (Email-ext plugin).

${BUILD_LOG_REGEX, regex, linesBefore, linesAfter, maxMatches, showTruncatedLines, substText}

Comment: Thanks Peter. BUILD_LOG_REGEX seems to be what I'm looking for. Updating the plugins once in a while is a good idea, since I missed that one with an older version of email-ext.